# Is there a Pytorch alternative for torch.cov on Pytorch 1.8.0?

Tags: python, pytorch, covariance

`torch.cov` doesn't seem to exist under Pytorch 1.8.0. Unfortunately, using a never version of Pytorch is not a solution for me because I work in a team and changing even one version of one library may take a long time.

So I am looking for another function which does the same as `torch.cov`

I can use `numpy.cov` as an alternative, but I'd like to know if I can use a `torch` function instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few solutions people used before `torch.cov()`:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19037